# What level do you need to be to participate in raid battles in Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while now since various sites I've looked at contradict one another or claim to know nothing. Anecdotal evidence suggests that the level requirement is Lv. 35 while I've seen friends at Lv. 25 initiate and participate in Raid Battles with no problem whatsoever, so what gives? I'm Lv. 20 right now, and I'd like to be able to join in on the fun, but so far, the game isn't letting me.

Comment: I'm sure you know this trick already, but stock up on Pidgey, Caterpie and Weedle candies (and anything else that requires 12 candies to evolve). Then load up a lucky egg and do a mass evolution of those Pokemon, only the first stage of each. Instead of 500XP per evolution, you will get 1,000XP. During a Double XP event, you can get 2,000XP per evolution. The amount of experience adds up very fast and can get you to the required level in no time.

Answer (score 8):

The level requirement is currently **25+**. It was 35, then lowered to 31, then 28, and finally to 25 (where it currently is). This all happened in one day earlier this week.

(I am level 22, so I feel your pain. I am really hoping that they change it to be somewhere around 15+ or 20+.)

Comment: The requirement is now 20+ as of today.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the required trainer level for raids is 20.

Source (Twitter):
@PokemonGoApp

> Trainers level 20 and above: You can now participate in Raid Battles at a wide variety of Gyms around the world.

Answer (score 4):

The current requirement is Level 5 and above as of [June 30th](https://twitter.com/PokemonGoApp/status/880943163430588416).

Answer (score -3):

I'm lvl 20 and I'm able to join in on the battles, 
but my little sis is lvl 17 and she's not able to 
join.
I think you have to be lvl 18 to join.

Comment: Please do not use text talk on SE. A minority of users may not understand. Additionally, please consider making your answer longer, and include proof such as screenshots.